# Is there a way to read cells in a client-side javascript script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I made a Google Form to let someone enter a file from Google Drive, with tags:[google form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUIQT.png) I then linked it to a Google sheet. Next, I wanted to make a HTML/JS page for people to view uploaded content, with a search bar for time, email address, and tags. I tried looking online, but I couldn't find anything. How can I read Google Sheet cells from (client-side) javascript?

I searched [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) for the answer, but I couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the way [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score 0):

**Getting Sheet Data from client side**

gs:

```
function getMyData(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const {sheet,range} = obj;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  const vs = sh.getRange(range).getValues();
  return vs;
}

function launchMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2').setWidth(600),"My Dialog")
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <title>Get Data from Server Side</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="data"></div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Sheet Name" id="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter range in A1 notation" id="range">
  <input type="button" value="Get Data" onClick="getData();">
  <script>
    function getData() {
      const sh = document.getElementById("name").value;
      const rg = document.getElementById("range").value;
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler((arr) => {
        let t = document.createElement("table");
        let ht = "";
        arr.forEach((r,i) => {
          ht += '<tr>'
          r.forEach((c,j) => {
            if(i==0) {
              ht += `<th style="border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold">${c}</th>`
            } else {
              ht += `<td style="border:1px solid black;">${c}</td>`
            }
            
          })
          ht += '</tr>';
        })
        ht+= '</table>'
        t.innerHTML = ht;
        document.getElementById("data").append(t);
      }).getMyData({sheet:sh,range:rg});
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]